# How do I return: a nested value, that's inside multiple indecis, within a JSON.parse API, into my google sheet cells?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm fetching data from this binance API(https://api1.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=ADAUSDT&interval=1d&limit=14).

I've, successfully, looped through the 'limit=14' parameter, which returns 0-13 indecis(or 14 indeces all together). These indeces contain various data on the pair specified in the 'symbol=ADAUSDT' parameter.

Now, theres 2 particular values I'm interested in: the high and the low of the day, which are in positions 2 and 3, respectively, in each index 0-13.

So, I've been able to log 0-13 results with the below script, but when I try to return the results to my sheet, it only populates the value in only one index, instead of 0-13.

How would I populate the results of my loop into the cells on my sheet?

```js
function atrCalculation() {
  var dailyHigh = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api1.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=ADAUSDT&interval=1d&limit=14");
  var jsonHighPrice = JSON.parse(dailyHigh);
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonHighPrice.length; i++) {
      data = jsonHighPrice[i];
      Logger.log(data[2]);
      Return data[i][2];
```

[function in cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHMVt.jpg)

[only one value produced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaNUM.jpg)

[Logger.log result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NrFE.jpg)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: "_when I try to return the results to my sheet, it only populates the value in one index, instead of 0-13_" - It looks like you have not shown us the relevant code. You only show the code which (correctly) fetches the API data. Show us the code which attempts to populate the spreadsheet. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: Very minor point: Instead of "indecis" which is not a word, I assume you mean "indices" - or even "indexes" if you prefer. Both are acceptable plurals for "index".

Comment: @andrewjames I added "Return data[i][2];" and corrected spelling.

Comment: If you want to return one specific value, use `return data[2]`, or whatever index you want instead of `2`. If you want to return all the values in each record, use `return data`. If you want to return a subset of the data, you can use `return data.slice(2, 5)` - which returns 3 values from the middle of the data array. And there are plenty of other options, depending on what you want...

Comment: ... But you said that the problem was writing the data to the spreadsheet, whereas now I think the problem is actually how to return an array containing only the 3 values you want from your function. I am not sure what the actual problem is you are facing.

Comment: @andrewjames Let me clarify: I loop the JSON.parse through 14 times as per the "limit=14" parameter, and assign the result to "data". My thought process is that "data" holds the 14 indexes that I can use to call positions 2 and 3 within each. That's to say, the values I'm looking for, across all the indexes, is in position 2 and 3 of each index. I believe these values are nested per the API link. I want those values, from all 14 indexes populated in the sheet. That would be 28 different values. I'm brand new to this so idk if I'm on the right track.

Comment: OK - so your problem is _not_ writing the data to a sheet (and you have not shown that code, anyway). Take a look at my `slice()` example - but `2` and `5` may be the wrong specific values you need - so you can change those. If that does not do what you want, then my apologies - I do not understand the problem. [more info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Comment: @andrewjames I've attached another screenshot of the result that Logger.log gives me. It's exactly how I want the data to populate into the cells in my sheet. I don't know how to properly write it into the cells. P.S. what does "Return data[i][2];" do? Thanks again

Comment: We've now come full circle back to my very first comment. Show us that code. (Maybe someone else can then help, after that. My attempts to help are clearly not helping. Sorry about that.)

Comment: @andrewjames I don't have any code is the thing. The ONLY thing I know how to do is the snippet that's available with this thread. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply retrieve all the data in your sheet 'klines' this way

```
function myKlines(){
  var url='https://api1.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=ADAUSDT&interval=1d&limit=14'
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
  var json = JSON.parse(source)
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('klines')
  sh.getRange(1, 1, json.length, json[0].length).setValues(json);
}
```